# How does a computer store, sort and process the events during a simulation implemented with with Simpy?

Tags: simpy

I'm facing a synchronization problem in Simpy. By that, I mean that events are not processed by the computer in the order I would like to. I have been looking a lot for more information than that already in Simpy documentation about how events are queued, sorted and processed by the computer. I found everywhere that it was sorted with respect to the time they have to be triggered at. Before reading the remaining, would anyone have any links or document to advise me?

More specifically, I am trying to model and simulate real world systems (an instance of the PoolSystem class), which is a pool of subsystems that can either be further broken down into sub-subsystems or be capable of failing (this last category of system is called AtomicSystem). So to sum up, a PoolSystem is made of subsystems that can be either a PoolSystem or an AtomicSystem.

For instance, a car could be an instance of this PoolSystem class, with an engine as subsystem. But an engine can be broken down into several other subsystems such as a piston or a sparking plug, which can actually fail. In this case, the engine would be defined as a PoolSystem instance and the piston and sparking plug as AtomicSystem instances.

The AtomicSystem and PoolSystem classes are based on the same standard model. They both have:

- a "critical" boolean attribute which is "True" if the failure of the given subsystem induces the failure of the whole system (which means that all other subsystems must be interrupted)
- an "update_order" event which acts as a signal for a system to communicate with its subsystems (if any)
- a "dysfunction_signal" event which is a signal for the subsystems to tell their system that they have failed
- a "interrupted" event which is triggered whenever the given system cannot work properly or whenever it has been interrupted by its higher level system
- an "update_end" event which acts as a signal for a subsystem to tell its higher level system that it has finished its update
- a "lifecycle" attribute which is the process that simulates the operational service of the given system

I hope the following schema can help understanding what you just read:
[The breakdown of a car defined as a Pool System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN8dW.png)

On this schema, the car is defined as a PoolSystem instance whose subsystems are the engine and the tyre. The tyre can be a firect cause of failure for the car so it is defined as an AtomicSystem instance. The engine is defined as another PoolSystem whose subsystems are a piston and a sparking plug, which can fail so are defined as AtomicSystem instances.

The class AtomicSystem can be found below:

```
class AtomicSystem(object):
def __init__(self, env, mtbd, backlog, user_defined_critical=True, ids=None):
    self.env = env                                       # environment()    
    self.mtbd = mtbd                                     # mean time between dysfunction
    self.critical = user_defined_critical                # boolean
    self.ids = ids                                       # list of strings
    self.ttd = self.time_to_dysfunction()                # time before dysfunction
    self.update_order = self.env.event()                 
    self.dysfunction_signal = self.env.event()           
    self.interrupted = self.env.event()
    self.update_end = self.env.event()
    self.lifecycle = self.env.process(self.run(backlog))

def time_to_dysfunction(self):
    return self.mtbd

def run(self, backlog):
    # the atomic system starts service when its update_order event is triggered
    yield self.update_order
    print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.ids[-1] + " starts service.")
    self.update_order = self.env.event()

    # atomic system specifies to higher level system that it has started service
    self.update_end.succeed()
    self.update_end = self.env.event()

    try:
        # as long as the atomic system remains in this while loop, it is said to be in service.
        while True:
            start = self.env.now
            time_out = self.env.timeout(self.ttd)

            # wait for a dysfunction (time_out) or interruption (interrupted) or an update from a higher level system (update_order)
            result = yield time_out | self.interrupted | self.update_order

            if time_out in result:
                print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.ids[-1] + " fails.")

                # if the atomic system fails, trigger dysfunction_signal event destined to be detected by higher level system
                self.dysfunction_signal.succeed()
                # when the atomic system fails, its interrupted event is automatically triggered 
                self.interrupted.succeed()
                if self.ttd > 0:
                    backlog.append({"Dysfunction time": self.env.now, "IDs": self.ids})
                self.ttd = 0

            if self.interrupted.triggered:
                print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.ids[-1] + " interrupts service.")
                if self.ttd > 0:
                    operation_duration = self.env.now - start
                    self.ttd -= operation_duration

                # the atomic system waits for update_order trigger when it has been interrupted
                yield self.update_order


            if self.update_order.triggered:
            # here, the atomic system returns to service
                print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.ids[-1] + " is updated.")
                if self.ttd > 0:
                    operation_duration = self.env.now - start
                    self.ttd -= operation_duration
                self.update_end.succeed()
                self.update_order = self.env.event()
                self.dysfunction_signal = self.env.event()
                self.interrupted = self.env.event()
                self.update_end = self.env.event()

    except:
    # here the atomic system is terminated (end of service)
        print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.ids[-1] + " is terminated.")
        self.env.exit()
```

The class PoolSystem can be found below:

```
class PoolSystem(object):
def __init__(self, env, id, init_subsystems, user_defined_critical=True):
    self.env = env
    self.id = id
    self.subsystems = init_subsystems
    self.working_subsystems = [self.subsystems[key] for key in self.subsystems.keys()]
    self.critical = user_defined_critical
    self.update_order = self.env.event()
    self.dysfunction_signal = simpy.AnyOf(self.env, [syst.dysfunction_signal for syst in self.working_subsystems])
    self.interrupted = self.env.event()
    self.update_end = self.env.event()
    self.lifecycle = self.env.process(self.run())

def start_subsystems(self):
    for key in self.subsystems.keys():
        self.subsystems[key].update_order.succeed()

def run(self):
    user_defined_critical = self.critical

    # the pool system is started here when its update_order event is triggered
    yield self.update_order
    print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.id + " starts service.")
    self.update_order = self.env.event()

    # Here, the pool system starts all of its subsystems (which can be atomic and/or pool systems)
    self.start_subsystems()

    # here, update_end is triggered if all the update_end events of the subsystems have been triggered
    self.update_end = simpy.AllOf(self.env, [self.subsystems[key].update_end for key in self.subsystems.keys()])
    yield self.update_end
    try:
        while True:

            # wait for a dysfunction (dysfunction_signal), interruption (interrupted) or an update from a higher level system (update_order)
            yield self.dysfunction_signal | self.interrupted | self.update_order


            if self.dysfunction_signal.triggered:
                crit = []
                for syst in self.working_subsystems:
                    if syst.dysfunction_signal.triggered:
                        crit.append(syst.critical)
                if True in crit: # if one of the failed subsystems is critical (critical = True), then trigger interrupted event()
                    print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.id + " fails completely.")
                    # pool system is interrupted
                    self.critical = user_defined_critical
                    self.interrupted.succeed()
                else:
                    # no critical subsystem has failed yet so the pool system can continue working (no interruption here)
                    self.critical = False
                    self.working_subsystems = [self.subsystems[key] for key in self.subsystems.keys() if
                                               not self.subsystems[key].interrupted.triggered]
                    if len(self.working_subsystems) is not 0:
                        print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.id + " fails partially.")
                        self.dysfunction_signal = simpy.AnyOf(self.env, [syst.dysfunction_signal for syst in
                                                                         self.working_subsystems])
                    else:
                    # pool system is interrupted if all of its subsystems have failed
                        print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.id + " fails completely (no working EUs).")
                        self.interrupted.succeed()

            if self.interrupted.triggered:
                print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.id + " interrupts service.")
                # interrupt all subsystems
                for key in self.subsystems.keys():
                    if not self.subsystems[key].interrupted.triggered:
                        self.subsystems[key].interrupted.succeed()

                # waits for update_order from higher level system
                yield self.update_order

            if self.update_order.triggered:
                print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.id + " is updated.")
                # update_order has been troggered by higher level system                    
                self.update_order = self.env.event()
                self.start_subsystems()
                self.update_end = simpy.AllOf(self.env,
                                              [self.subsystems[key].update_end for key in self.subsystems.keys()])
                # wait for the end of the update of the subsystems
                yield self.update_end
                print("t = " + str(self.env.now) + " : " + self.id + " receives update-end signal.")
                self.working_subsystems = [self.subsystems[key] for key in self.subsystems.keys()]
                self.dysfunction_signal = simpy.AnyOf(self.env,
                                                      [syst.dysfunction_signal for syst in self.working_subsystems])
                self.interrupted = self.env.event()


    except simpy.Interrupt:
    # here the pool system is terminated, it leaves service.
        for key in self.subsystems.keys():
            self.subsystems[key].lifecycle.interrupt()
        self.env.exit()
```

I have defined two other classes, Eu (inheriting from AtomicSystem) and ModSat (inheriting from PoolSystem). Basically, I'm building a modsat object out of several Eu objects (only two system levels). I have posted the code below:

```
class Eu(AtomicSystem):
def __init__(self, env, identity, mtbd, backlog, critical=True, ids=None):
    self.id = identity
    ids.append(self.id)
    AtomicSystem.__init__(self, env, mtbd, backlog, critical, ids)

class ModSat(PoolSystem):
def __init__(self, env, digit_id, eu_mtbds_criticals, backlog, critical=True):
    identity = "ModSat" + str(digit_id)
    self.eus = self.initialize(env, identity, eu_mtbds_criticals, backlog)
    PoolSystem.__init__(self, env, identity, self.eus, critical)

def initialize(self, env, identity, eu_mtbds_criticals, backlog):
    eus = {}
    for i in range(1, len(eu_mtbds_criticals) + 1):
        eu_id = "EU" + str(i) + ":" + identity
        eu = Eu(env, eu_id, eu_mtbds_criticals[i - 1][0], backlog, eu_mtbds_criticals[i - 1][1], [identity])
        eus[eu_id] = eu
    return eus
```

Finally, I wanted to test ModSat objects and see if I could easily replace one of the failed subsystems (Eu type) of a modsat object without affecting the good behavior of the modsat. I created a simulate function which enables me to interact with the modsat objects. I ran the tests with 2 modsat objects defined by:

```
backlog = []
eu_mtbds_criticals1 = [[5, False], [11, False], [19, False]]
eu_mtbds_criticals2 = [[4, False], [27, False], [38, False]]
env = simpy.Environment()
sat1 = ModSat(env, 1, eu_mtbds_criticals1, backlog, True)
sat2 = ModSat(env, 2, eu_mtbds_criticals2, backlog, True)
constellation = {'ModSat1': sat1, 'ModSat2': sat2}
env.process(simulate(constellation, env, backlog))
env.run(until=100)
```

The first test was very simple with the following simulate function:

```
def simulate(constellation, env, backlog):
for key in constellation.keys():
    # start service of each ModSat object included in the constellation dictionary, 
    # by triggering their update_order event.
    constellation[key].update_order.succeed()

# wait for a while to be sure that the modsat objects have been completely simulated.
yield env.timeout(50)
```

The output is what I wanted because all the events seem to have been triggered and processed in the right order by the computer:

```
# the 1st update_order event of PoolSystem is triggered
t = 0 : ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : ModSat2 starts service.
# the 1st update_order event of AtomicSystem is triggered
t = 0 : EU1:ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : EU3:ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : EU2:ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : EU2:ModSat2 starts service.
t = 0 : EU1:ModSat2 starts service.
t = 0 : EU3:ModSat2 starts service.
# 1st failure here. Since critical attribute of EU1:ModSat2 is set to False ModSat2 is not interrupted (partial failure)
t = 4 : EU1:ModSat2 fails.
t = 4 : EU1:ModSat2 interrupts service.
t = 4 : ModSat2 fails partially.
# 2nd failure here
t = 5 : EU1:ModSat1 fails.
t = 5 : EU1:ModSat1 interrupts service.
t = 5 : ModSat1 fails partially.
t = 11 : EU2:ModSat1 fails.
t = 11 : EU2:ModSat1 interrupts service.
t = 11 : ModSat1 fails partially.
# here the last failure of ModSat1: ModSat1 is interrupted because it has no more working Eus
t = 19 : EU3:ModSat1 fails.
t = 19 : EU3:ModSat1 interrupts service.
t = 19 : ModSat1 fails completely (no working EUs).
t = 19 : ModSat1 interrupts service.
t = 27 : EU2:ModSat2 fails.
t = 27 : EU2:ModSat2 interrupts service.
t = 27 : ModSat2 fails partially.
# here the last failure of ModSat2: ModSat2 is interrupted because it has no more working Eus
t = 38 : EU3:ModSat2 fails.
t = 38 : EU3:ModSat2 interrupts service.
t = 38 : ModSat2 fails completely (no working EUs).
t = 38 : ModSat2 interrupts service.
```

Now, I want to test my code with the following simulate function:

```
def simulate(constellation, env, backlog):
    for key in constellation.keys():
    # start service of each ModSat object included in the constellation dictionary, 
    # by triggering their update_order event.
        constellation[key].update_order.succeed()


    # detect failure
    request_signal = simpy.AnyOf(env, [constellation[key].dysfunction_signal for key in constellation.keys()])
    yield request_signal

    # The servicer's backlog is updated with the first item of the backlog list
    print("t = " + str(env.now) + " : a service request is detected.")
    servicer_backlog = []
    servicer_backlog.append(backlog[0])
    del backlog[0]

    # the next line models the servicer time of service
    yield env.timeout(5)

    # The servicer gets the ID of the failed Eu to replace from its backlog
    sat_id = servicer_backlog[0]['IDs'][0]
    eu_id =  servicer_backlog[0]['IDs'][1]
    failed_eu = constellation[sat_id].eus[eu_id]
    # the servicer gives the values of the attributes of the failed EU to the new EU
    new_eu = Eu(failed_eu.env, failed_eu.id, failed_eu.mtbd, backlog, failed_eu.critical, failed_eu.ids)
    # the failed eu is terminated (its service ends)
    failed_eu.lifecycle.interrupt()
    # the new EU replaces the failed_eu
    constellation[sat_id].eus[eu_id] = new_eu
    # the modsat concerned by the replacement has its update_order event triggered
    constellation[sat_id].update_order.succeed()
    print("t = " + str(env.now) + " : a service is provided")
```

The simulate function above just models the replacement of the first  failed Eu with a new one. The output is:

```
# the 1st update_order event of PoolSystem is triggered
t = 0 : ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : ModSat2 starts service.
# the 1st update_order event of AtomicSystem is triggered
t = 0 : EU3:ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : EU2:ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : EU1:ModSat1 starts service.
t = 0 : EU1:ModSat2 starts service.
t = 0 : EU2:ModSat2 starts service.
t = 0 : EU3:ModSat2 starts service.
t = 0 : ModSat1 receives update-end signal.
t = 0 : ModSat2 receives update-end signal.
# the first Eu of modsat2 fails, and its failure is detected by the simulate function
t = 4 : EU1:ModSat2 fails.
t = 4 : EU1:ModSat2 interrupts service.
t = 4 : a service request is detected.
t = 4 : ModSat2 fails partially.
# HERE IS MY CONCERN: at time t = 5, EU1 of modsat1 fails and interrupts service. However, there should be a line "t = 5 : ModSat1 fails partially" which does not appear... 
t = 5 : EU1:ModSat1 fails.
t = 5 : EU1:ModSat1 interrupts service.
t = 9 : a service is provided
t = 9 : EU1:ModSat2 is terminated.
t = 9 : ModSat2 is updated.
t = 9 : EU1:ModSat2 starts service.
t = 9 : EU2:ModSat2 is updated.
t = 9 : EU3:ModSat2 is updated.
t = 9 : ModSat2 receives update-end signal.
t = 11 : EU2:ModSat1 fails.
t = 11 : EU2:ModSat1 interrupts service.
t = 13 : EU1:ModSat2 fails.
t = 13 : EU1:ModSat2 interrupts service.
t = 13 : ModSat2 fails partially.
t = 19 : EU3:ModSat1 fails.
t = 19 : EU3:ModSat1 interrupts service.
t = 27 : EU2:ModSat2 fails.
t = 27 : EU2:ModSat2 interrupts service.
t = 27 : ModSat2 fails partially.
t = 38 : EU3:ModSat2 fails.
t = 38 : EU3:ModSat2 interrupts service.
t = 38 : ModSat2 fails completely (no working EUs).
t = 38 : ModSat2 interrupts service.
```

As indicated above, there should be a line at "t = 5 : ModSat1 fails partially" after the line "t = 5 : EU1:ModSat1 interrupts service". But instead, the computer jumps directly to the first line after the "yield env.timeout(5)" of the simulate function.

I don't understand what happens here, I think that's because of my lack of knowledge about how is defined and sorted the queue of events by Simpy. I could not find any hint online of what's going on here. I have not seen any question of this kind on stackoverflow and other forums. I would gladly appreciate any help.

My code is quite long to explain so I hope that the comments in the code I posted are sufficient :\

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I (finally) started a guide about time in SimPy.  It is still WIP, but you can follow the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-simpy/4vG13DUeC34).